# magento customize module Log functionality

Tags: php, magento

I have created a custom module in Magento. Now I want to log(Debug) my module flow and processing function in Log/Debug file.

I know Mage::Log() function will do this but I want to customize its with my own log file. 
So that I can view it another window.

Where should I write the Logger method so that I can access the method in all resource of Module like Module,Block,Controller and Helpers..

Please help me-

-Pravin

Answer (score 3):

You can use method from `/app/Mage.php`

```
public static function log($message, $level = null, $file = '', $forceLog = false)
```

The 3d parameter is file, you can specify it and all log messages will be in it.

```
Mage::log('Some exseption', Zend_Log::ERR, 'my_module.log');
```

Comment: Yes, that's I know that, but I want to write a function which uses Mage::Log method in my module which easily callable to modules resources like mymodule->writeLog('log data','mode',file)...so every time I don't want to create an object of my newly created log class and create object and then call log method.. hope you understand...

Comment: Why it's a problem to call `Mage::log` explicitly?

Comment: I am not understanding why you would need this functionality instead of `Mage::Log()` as this is callable from all the files you mentioned already?

Answer (score 2):

If I understand your question correctly; the best place to put such a method would be in your module's helper.

**app/code/local/My/Module/Helper/Data.php**:

```
class My_Module_Helper_Data extends Mage_Core_Helper_Data
{
    public function myLog( $desc, $val, $log = 'my_module.log' ) {
        return Mage::log( $desc, $val, $log );
    }
}
```

This way you can call your own log via the module helper class:

```
Mage::helper('my_module')->myLog( 'A variable: ', $val );
```

However, I do agree with @viakondratiuk that this might not be a great idea, since it's more complicated that the default `Mage::log` method.

Comment: can you change log path like var/support/test.log instead of var/log/test.log